# How to install Rails application on ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While installing, some errors are displayed. The command I am using is:

```
sudo gem install rails --include-dependencies
```

or

```
sudo gem install rails --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

In both cases, it is the same error. I think my rubygems may not be installed properly?

```
ERROR: Loading command: install (LoadError) no such file to load -- zlib ERROR: While executing gem ... (NameError) uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

I have installed ruby-1.9.2-p0 and rubygems-1.3.7

One more thing: Do I have to `cd` into the ruby or rubygems directory and then install rails or can I do it from default directory?

Comment: neha, post the error message you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Open command prompt and please let us know the results

verify Ruby version

`ruby -v`

verify gem version

`gem -v`

Use command

`gem install rails`

verify the rails version

`rails -v`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby1.9 gem1.9
```

Answer (score 0):

checkout below mentioned link that would help you to install rails3 using rvm on ubuntu box
http://www.jaikeerthi.in/2010/11/install-rails-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

You have to install zlib1g and zlib1g-dev

```
sudo aptitude install zlib1g zlib1g-dev
```

Some GEMs compile some binaries at installation time and need other libraries (such as zlib) be installed on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are installing on Ubuntu 14.04...

First install rbev to pick a Ruby version for your application.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the rbenv and Ruby dependencies with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev
```

Now let's install rbenv

```
 cd

git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
```

`echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

```
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile

git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build

echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.bash_profile
```

And now let's install Ruby:

```
rbenv install -v 2.2.3
rbenv global 2.2.3
```

Verify that Ruby is installed with this command:

```
ruby -v
```

Install bundler to manage gems:

```
gem install bundler
```

Now we are set to install Rails:

```
gem install rails
```

Then run

```
rbenv rehash
```

It's good to verify if the Rails is installed properly:

```
rails -v
```

Make sure to install database and Javascript runtime afterwards...